# Magento 2 - How to install extension from marketplace.magento.com via composer?

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2marketplace

I bought a [this extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-customer-approval.html) from marketplace.magento.com. I tried to install it via composer like this:

```
composer require bsscommerce/customer-approval
```

But I get

> [InvalidArgumentException] Could not find a matching version of
> package bsscommerce/customer-approval. Check the package spelling,
> your version constraint and that the package is available in a
> stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

I also followed this [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/install/), but it does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the BSSCommerce instructions on how to install the extensions via composer.

Those can be found here: https://wiki.bsscommerce.com/docs/faqs/install-magento-extension/install-magento-2-composer/

Comment: Thanks, I am one step further. Now it asks me for credentials. I created access keys in marketplace.magento.com and used them, but it says "invalid credentials."

Comment: You need the accesskeys from BSSCommerce, check step1 on how to get them:

"Step 1: Create Access Keys And Get The Package Information
Send us an email to sales@bsscommerce.com along with the order number. We will create access keys as your requirement and then provide you with information about the packages."

Answer (score 1):

I see you purchased an extension on Marketplace

Since Marketplace has their own composer and installation system, you could not use the composer installation guide: https://wiki.bsscommerce.com/docs/faqs/install-magento-extension/install-magento-2-composer/

-> Instead, you will need to get the composer keys and follow the installation guide from Marketplace

REFERENCES:

- To get the keys: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html
- To install: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/tutorials/extensions.html?lang=en